# Rolling my own Require

Tags: javascript, class, require

**Forward**

It has come to my attention that this problem was a "Function Scoping - Not Block Scoping" answer, the difference being `for ... in` opposed to `for ... i<n ... i++` The solution could be wrapping the `for(var p in ...) {` with a function to give them their own scope (much like was done with `Array.prototype.forEach`). Thank you for your help.

**Problem**

I'm rolling my own tiny Require.js solution as opposed to the actual Require.js library (no I haven't taken a look at their source).

My callback function never seems to be executed, but I can't figure out why. It's probably a simple logical error, but you know how it goes when you stare at your own code for too long. (Everything looks logically sound)

**Usage**

Used as follows:

```
require(["LibraryA", "LibraryB", "LibraryC"], function() {
    //code which requires libraries a-c here
});
```

**Code**

```
var require = (function() {
    var scriptsLoaded = [];
    return function(paths, callback) {
        var pathsDoneLoading = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            pathsDoneLoading[paths[i]] = false;
        }
        for(var p in pathsDoneLoading) {
            for(var i = 0; i < scriptsLoaded.length; i++) {
                if(p === scriptsLoaded[i]) {
                    pathsDoneLoading[p] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for(var p in pathsDoneLoading) {
            if(pathsDoneLoading[p] === false) {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = p + ".js";
                script.onload = function() {
                    scriptsLoaded.push(p);
                    pathsDoneLoading[p] = true;
                    for(var p in pathsDoneLoading) {
                        if(pathsDoneLoading[p] !== true) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    callback();
                };
                document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

**Plunker**

https://plnkr.co/edit/OFWTUpmV3sIJAjhGhcLO

Comment: Shouldn't the callback be called after all the script elements have been created? Right now it looks like you want to call it after every script has been loaded

Comment: You're defining `require` as a self-executing method? Considering dropping the trailing `();`

Comment: My thought was, "Return if one of the paths isn't done" which led me to assume "callback by default if we made it here"

Comment: @Sean3z it's a IIFE because I need a persistent list of scripts already loaded.. I suppose there are other patterns I could have used, any suggestions?

Comment: This problem looks interesting, can you post a reproducible example in Plnkr? https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the old `for` loop variable catching problem.

During your loop where it's iterating through what paths are loading (`for (var p in pathsDoneLoading) {`) the `p` is being bound to the function inside. The problem is that `p` changes and persists after the loop has complete so every single function is adding the *last* key in the `pathsDoneLoading` object to the `scriptsLoaded` array (and setting the matching value in `pathsDoneLoading` to `true`).

An example of the problem:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var funcs = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  funcs.push(function() {
    return key; // Remember, `key` is bound to the function, not the block
  });
}

funcs.forEach(function(f) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += f() + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

To fix this, you can wrap it in an IIFE to create a new binding per `p` value.

```
for (var p in pathsDoneLoading) {
  (function(p) {
    if (pathsDoneLoading[p] === false) { // or `if (!pathsDoneLoading[p])`
    ...
  })(p);
}
```

That way every time you generate an `onload` handler, they have a unique binding to the intended path.

Our previous example fixed with this solution:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var funcs = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  (function(key) {
    funcs.push(function() {
      return key; // Remember, `key` is bound to the function, not the block
    });
  })(key);
}

funcs.forEach(function(f) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += f() + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you'll need capture the for loop iterator because it's a moving target and by the time onload fires, it will have changed.

```
    var require = (function() {
    var scriptsLoaded = [];
    return function(paths, callback) {
        var pathsDoneLoading = {};
        for(var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            pathsDoneLoading[paths[i]] = false;
        }
        for(var p in pathsDoneLoading) {
            for(var i = 0; i < scriptsLoaded.length; i++) {
                if(p === scriptsLoaded[i]) {
                    pathsDoneLoading[p] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for(var p in pathsDoneLoading) {
            if(pathsDoneLoading[p] === false) {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.src = p + ".js";

                // Wrapping in a closure
                script.onload = (function(Vp) {
                    scriptsLoaded.push(Vp);
                    pathsDoneLoading[Vp] = true;
                    for(var prop in pathsDoneLoading) {
                        if(pathsDoneLoading[prop] !== true) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    callback();

                // Execute the closure function and send in your 
                // var(s) as argument(s) to capture it's current state
                }(p));
                document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, you're not returning anything when you invoke the `onload` IIFE, and your `(p)` parameter syntax is incorrect, but I did implement this solution in my code other than that, and it worked.

Comment: Cool. Just trying to keep things simple for you and not over-write your original code. Javascript is rather forgiving. The point to focus on is the p to Vp relationship.